# How to use VPN only for some of the applications running?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn

I am using Microsoft Team and our company Gitlab. For accessing gitlab I need to use VPN but MS Team is not working with VPN, is there a way that I configure Ubuntu to use VPN for everything except MS Team?

BTW our company is using Cisco openconnect.

Comment: Some ideas perhaps here. Not trivial. https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-applications

Comment: You cannot control it on application level, but on a network connection level. You would need to know what servers you connect to when using MS Teams and exclude those from the routing through the VPN. An example is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592248/cisco-vpn-connection-only-for-ssh?rq=1), but you would need to adapt it of course.